# Promblem finding empty elements in a comma seperated data

Tags: java, pattern-matching

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class test { 

public static void main(String args[]) {

    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    String s = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g";
    StringTokenizer st  = new StringTokenizer(s,",");

    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
        data.add(st.nextToken());
    }
    System.out.println(data);

}

}
```

Problem in finding empty elements in a CSV data
the above code works well when the data is complete. If some data is missing it fails to detect the empty data.

ex: 
Complete DATA : a,b,c,d,e,f,g

if a,d,e,g are removed

New DATA : ,b,c,,,f,

4 data missing!!

I need a way to put this data into ArrayList with null or "" values for empty data

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Please add more information so that we can get some idea about what '4 data missing' means.

Comment: How does your code look like? Also are you using CSV parser?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are more elegant solutions, but a simple one would be to use [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) function:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    String s = ",b,c,,,f,";

    //create an array of strings, using "," as a delimiter
    //if there is no letter between commas, an empty string will be 
    //placed in strings[] instead
    String[] strings = s.split(",", -1);

    for (String ss : strings) {
        data.add(ss);
    }

    System.out.println(data);
}
```

Comment: Already tried this,
Problems: 
1. doesnt detect last missing elemnet
2. split is slow for huge data

Comment: for last element theres only one comma.

Comment: @Anshul If you use split with negative limit last empty elements will be included. Try `s.split(",", -1);`

Comment: From the docs: StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead. EDIT: works with Pshemo's modification, edited my code

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I am looking for a faster solution. Using 
This is just one data. I have a 3gb file as below
a,b,c,....|a1,b1,c1,....|a2,b2...

to read.

StringTokeniser makes my code 2X faster. Any other faster solutions without Split?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Guava Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) to do that:

```
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;

public class Example
{  
    private static final Splitter SPLITTER = Splitter.on(",").trimResults();

    public List<String> split(String singleLine) {
        return SPLITTER.split(singleLine);        
    }
}
```